# How do I personalize variables in Jina2 template for individual hosts belonging to group host inventory?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, jinja2

I have this line of code in jinja template:

```
Host ({address={{peer_ip}}:28112, name={{inventory_host}}, pool="dynamite"})
```

For example on host1, host2 respectively I expect these lines generated with slight change for custom address and name of host on which it is running:

Host1

```
Host ({address=192.168.21.2:28112, name=host1, pool="dynamite"})
```

Host2

```
Host ({address=192.168.21.7:28112, name=host2, pool="dynamite"})
```

This is my inventory file:

```
all:
  hosts:
    host00[1:9].example.com:
```

I want to avoid creating inventory file or playbook for each new server.

```
tasks:
  
- name: copy modified template file
  template:
    src: preconfig.txt.j2
    dest: /etc/program/configured.txt

vars:
 peer_ip:
   - 192.168.21.2
   - 192.168.21.6
   - 192.168.59.3
```

```
{% if inventory_host ... %}
Host ({address={{peer_ip}}:28112, name={{inventory_host}}, pool="dynamite"})
{% endif %}
```

```
if running on inventory_host==host1:
   Host ({address=192.168.21.2:28112, name=host1, pool="dynamite"})
```

Where do I start? Can I get inventory_host from ansible_facts on which playbook is run? How do I write vars for peer_ips that playbook knows for example peer_ip== 192.168.21.2 for inventory_host==host1?

Comment: This is all very unclear. 1) You talk about e.g. `host1` but your hosts is named `host001(.example.com)` in your inventory. What do you want to compare against exactly? The hostname configured on the target? Or the one in you inventory? See [magic varialble](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic-variables) `inventory_hostname` and `inventory_hostname_short` for this last one. 2) What is `peer_ip` supposed to contain? The configure host IP on target? Something from your list? in last case, how do you select the correct ip for the correct host?

Comment: Please do not reply in comments: [edit] your question.